# line spacing in title is too narrow

Tags: line-spacing

I have a template for my thesis and the line spacing is too narrow for the department title.

It looks like in the image.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W-FLfpB5vv6mOEUvCVu4_zYiOL2MWq3N/view?usp=sharing

The command in the title file is this:

```
\vspace{5mm}
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty{}}}\\
\vspace{15mm}
```

In the main.tex file it's this:

```
\newcommand*{\getFaculty}{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering}
```

I don't understand how I can increase the line spacing for only this line beacuse for the other lines it looks good.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The line spacing of a changed font doesn't get applied until the end of a paragraphj -- and this element doesn't get treated as a paragraph, so the default spacing is applied.  Add `\par` just before the final brace to force it.  That shouldn't change anything else.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `\renewcommand*{\medskip\getFaculty}{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering} as a work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two remedies.

- The canonical solution, already suggested by barbara beeton, is to insert a `\par` instruction *before* the scope of `\huge` ends. That way, the interline spacing that's applied is what's appropriate for `\huge` material.
- Insert `\strut` directives immediately before and after `\getFaculty`.

I'd recommend using the former solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\getFaculty}{Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering}

\begin{document}
\centering
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty}\par}

\bigskip

{\huge\MakeUppercase{\strut\getFaculty\strut}}
\end{document}
```

---

In addition, you should seriously consider letterspacing all-caps material. The following screenshot shows the appearance without and with letterspacing, for all-caps and small-caps material. Letterspacing can be achieved by using the `\textls` command, which is provided by the `letterspace` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\getFaculty}{Department of Electrical and~Computer Engineering}
\usepackage{letterspace} % for "\textls" macro
\textwidth13cm

\begin{document}
\centering
{\huge\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty}\par}

\bigskip
{\huge\textls{\MakeUppercase{\getFaculty}}\par}

\bigskip
{\huge\textsc{\getFaculty}\par}

\bigskip
{\huge\textls[75]{\textsc{\getFaculty}}\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! \par is not working. It says "There is no line here to end."
\strut works just fine! Thanks.

Comment: @aJazz - As the screenshot shows, using `\par` works just fine with a basic but fairly standard document setup. If `\par` "is not working" for your docuent, it must be because of some nonstandard characteristics of your document which you haven't shared so far.